# Multiple regular vertical tableviews inside of one horizontal collectionview

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, nested, horizontal-scrolling

Hello I am trying to display multiple vertical table views inside of ONE horizontal view on iOS. Is this possible?  The table views themselves should be able to scroll vertically like normal but I should also be able to scroll horizontally between multiple tableviews, all in the same viewcontroller (if possible). I have attached an image of what it should look like . As you can see, I should be able to scroll the tableviews vertically independently from the horizontal scrolling that is used to display different tableviews. All while keeping the header visible (Engineering, Scholarships, etc.

What strategy should be done on iOS/Swift, is there a tutorial? I am OK with using a UICollectionView instead or any other type of view. Thanks so much!

[image: how the tableviews should look]

Comment: Did you find something? I'm looking for something similar @ben Akin

Comment: Nope. I ended up changing the design. I had one horizontal collectionview at the top. And when I selected item from that view it changed a table View at the bottom

Comment: @UserID0908 see above